# topological sort and parallel task scheduling

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, order-theory

I was reading MIT's reading notes on relations and partial orders. In doing so I came across a section which said that because posets have topological sort, it will helps us in executing tasks sequentially. Then it says that for any posets there is a legal parallel schedule that runs in t steps where t is the length of longest chain. To prove this claim I came across this theorem:
[image]

I don't understand the last sentence "for all a in Ai, we have that all b<_a appear in the set A U...UAi-1." what does it mean by " for all a in Ai". What does a refer to in a in Ai?

Comment: $A_i\subset A$. For any element $a$ of that subset, any element in $b\in A$ that is less than or equal to $a$ must be in one of the subsets that precede $A_i$ in the chain.

Comment: Hi @JohnDouma thanks for you response. I'm still having a bit problem. Can you open the following link and check figure 7.13 on page 21 and help me understand the last line using that as an example. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/efac321fdc8d0b27586ca35b04aab808_MIT6_042JF10_chap07.pdf

Comment: Before you can put on your shoes you must put on your socks. But it doesn't matter which sock you put on first nor does it matter which shoe you put on first. In this case, "less than or equal to" means must come before. This definition is saying that the items in a particular $A_i$, say $A_2$, don't depend upon each other. The items in $A_1$ must be done before the items in $A_2$ which must be done before items in $A_3$, etc.

Comment: So basically the last sentence of the theorem simple says that any element that is less than or equal to say some element of A2 must be in A1. So A3 subset in the example contains {left shoe, right shoe, belt}. The element "left sock" is less than left shoe and indeed it is in the subset A1 which obviously precedes A3. Right?

Comment: I believe you have it.

Comment: Hi @JohnDouma Could you help me understand the proof of the following lemma:  "For all t > 0, every partially ordered set with n elements must have either a chain of size greater than t or an antichain of size at least n/t"
Proof. By contradiction. Assume that the longest chain has length at most t and the longest antichain has size less than n=t. Then by Corollary 7.9.2( this is mentioned on page 23), the n elements can be partitioned into at most t antichains. Hence, there are fewer than t*n/t = n elements in the poset, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @JohnDouma How did they came to the conclusion that there are fewer than n elements in the poset?